# How can I check what paramters a method gets with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Let's say that I have a class called MyClass, basically I want to do something like this:

```
class MyClass   
  def initialize(a)
    do_stuff a, 4, 11   
  end

  def do_stuff(a,b,c)
     # ...   
  end 
end


# rspec below 
MyClass.any_instance.should_receive(:do_stuff).with_the_values(10, 
     anything, anything) 
MyClass.new 10
```

Basically, I want to check that initialize will call on, and pass the correct value to `do_stuff`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should test if your class behaves correctly or not instead of watching who passes what to whom.

I guess, the `do_stuff` method is supposed to produce a side-effect of some sort. If so, then check if this side-effect is the one you expect. This way you're free to change actual implementation of your class without needing to rewrite your specs every time.